# Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

So i'm coming across this problem with someone trying to load this page that doesn't have an email address and I'm having difficulty finding a work around.

```
//getting email address for current user
    IIdentity id = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
    WindowsIdentity winId = id as WindowsIdentity;
    if (id != null)
    {
        userName = winId.Name;

        string userInQuestion = userName.Split('\\')[1];
        string myDomain = userName.Split('\\')[0]; // this is the domain that the user is in
        // the account that this program runs in should be authenticated in there                    

        using (HostingEnvironment.Impersonate())
        {
            DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + myDomain);
            DirectorySearcher adSearcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry);

            adSearcher.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
            adSearcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(samaccountname=" + userInQuestion + "))";
            SearchResult userObject = adSearcher.FindOne();
            if (userObject != null)
            {
                string[] props = new string[] { "mail"};
                {
                    foreach (string prop in props)
                    {
                        if (userObject.Properties[prop][0].ToString() != "")
                        {
                            CurrentUserEmail = userObject.Properties[prop][0].ToString();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            CurrentUserEmail = "";
                        }
                    }

                }
            }

        }
    }
```

This is the stack trace that i'm getting, i understand that some people who submit this form might not have email addresses but I cant seem to find a work around for the problem. The if else statement that's there was my most recent attempt but the error still exists.

[image]

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: CurrentUserEmail = userObject.Properties[pro][0].toString();

Comment: I'm having trouble finding a work around if email doesn't exist in the property. the if/else statement is still getting me the same error

Comment: Here, this might help You. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.searchresult.properties%28v=vs.110%29.aspx ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is the `[0]` in `userObject.Properties[prop][0].ToString()`

If the array is empty; i.e. there are no elements, than you will receive the error.
try

```
CurrentUserEmail = "";
var propertyArray = userObject.Properties[prop];
if (propertyArray.Lenght > 0) CurrentUserEmail = propertyArray[0] as string;
```

Comment: You're suggesting rudy that i try your code within the foreach loop?

Answer (score 0):

Why not catch the exception and assign the email address to "" in the catch block?

Comment: so try wrapping this around a try catch and assign email adddress to "" in the catch exception?

Comment: sorry if my question seems a litlle lame. This is my first job ib the field, only been at it a month, not done with school yet, but i had figured the if/else in the block of code would of taken care of that.

Comment: Yes, either catch the exception that is thrown or better yet use the Length property test Rudi suggested.